# Не работает classList.remove()

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/Ssivenkov/pen/oNBWORm

Почему `classList.remove()` работает для кнопок управления скролом, но не работает для кнопки `close`? Как сделать чтобы работало на кнопке `close`?

```
<body>
<section>
    <div class="cart-btn"><p class="cart-text">cart</p>
        <div class="popup-cart">
            <div class="popup-cart__area"></div>
            <div class="popup-cart__container">
                <div class="popup-cart__content">
          <p>text</p>
                    <div class="order-buttons-box">
                        <div class="order-buttons__close">close</div>
                        <div class="off">OFF-SCROLL</div>
                        <div class="on">ON-SCROLL</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
<p>text for test</p><br>
</body>
```

```
.cart-scroll-off {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.popup-cart-visible {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.cart-btn {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 25;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cart-text {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.popup-cart {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.popup-cart__area {
  cursor: default;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.popup-cart__container {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-cart__content {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 23vw;
  max-width: 95vw;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.order-buttons-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.order-buttons__close, .on, .off {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```
let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".order-buttons__close");
let cartBtn = document.querySelector(".cart-btn");
let cartWindow = document.querySelector(".popup-cart");
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let off = document.querySelector(".off");
let on = document.querySelector(".on");

function offFunc() {
   body.classList.add("cart-scroll-off");
}
function onFunc() {
   body.classList.remove("cart-scroll-off");
}
function openFunc() {
   cartWindow.classList.add("popup-cart-visible");
}
function closeFunc() {
   cartWindow.classList.remove("popup-cart-visible");
}

off.addEventListener("click", offFunc);
on.addEventListener("click", onFunc);
cartBtn.addEventListener("click", openFunc);
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeFunc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы зачем-то попап помещаете внутрь кнопки. Сначала класс убирается как вы и хотите, но затем событие клика поднимается к родительской кнопке попапа и там класс ставится снова.

Можете сделать так:

```
function closeFunc(event){
   event.stopPropagation(); // Запрет всплытия события
   cartWindow.classList.remove("popup-cart-visible");
}
```